# OverflowError: range() result has too many items, although it hasn't

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this for-loop:

```
for i in range(1000000000, 1000000030):
    foo(i)
```

When I execute it this error is given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/CENSORED/Activity.py", line 11, in <module>
    for i in range(1000000000, 10000000030):
OverflowError: range() result has too many items.
```

As far as I know, this `range`-object should have exactly 30 elements...

Where is the problem?

Edit:

I have removed the extra zero, now I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/CENSORED/Activity.py", line 12, in <module>
    factorizeInefficient(i)
MemoryError
```

Edit 2:

```
def factorizeInefficient(n):
    teiler = list()
    for i in range(n):
        if i != 0:
            if (n%i)==0:
                teiler.append(i)
    print teiler
```

**Just found the solution myself:** There is a range(n) object in this as well and this causes the memory Error...

An extra question: How did you guys know this was python 2? (Btw you were right...)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778764/python-overflowerror#10778815), you might find it useful.

Comment: If you're on python 2.7, then you should use xrange instead of range.

Comment: Because you are on Python 2, and `range` will create a `list` object. This list-object will require, *just for the pointers in the underlying array*, something like `9000000030 * 8 * 1e-9 == 72` gigabytes. You can add at least another 28 bytes per actual `int` object contained in the list, bringing you to `297` gigabytes

Comment: @VasilisG. But this range object should only generate the 30 numbers inbetween my numbers, shouldn't it?

Comment: Range is creating a list that is too big and it is running out of memory.

Comment: @monamona there aren't 30 ints. there are `10000000030 - 1000000000 == 9000000030` ints.

Comment: You have an extra 0 in the second number

Comment: @NendoTaka I removed it, then I got an memoryError instead ^^

Comment: @monamona I think that @juanpa.arrivilaga is right. You must have enter an extra `0` in `range`'s end value.

Comment: `range()` in Python 3 is like `xrange()` in Python 2:  it returns an iterator in Python 3 instead of a list.  So Python 3 doesn't care how many elements it has.  Python 2 has to construct a list with that many elements, and it was exceedingly unlikely you're running on a machine with enough memory to hold 9 billion ints ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy/pasting the `range()` part of your code:

```
>>> len(range(1000000000, 10000000030))
9000000030
```

So there are actually about 9 billion elements in the range.  Your first argument is presumably missing a zero, or second argument has a zero too many ;-)

Comment: Note that these errors are more easily avoided if you write large numbers in arithmetic, i.e.:
`range(1000 * 1000 * 1000, 1000 * 1000 * 1000 + 30)`

It saves you time keeping track and your computer won't even notice the extra work.

Answer (score 1):

count your zeros once again ;) I'd say it's one too much.